# mongoose - nodejs - has no method for some reason

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Having some issues!

The error is

```
local: 
  { password: '$2a$08$kSflSzcciqWN78nfqAu/4.ZBZaXkqb19bEypeWcuSxg89yPNuijYO',
    email: '***@gmail.com' } } has no method 'usersCharacters'
```

But it does have the method!
I am not sure it is being exported properly. As far as I can tell I am doing it similarly to the other methods users have except here it doesn't seem to work.

user.js model file

```
....
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);


/* method works :D ! -- not sure if over complicated though! */
UserSchema.methods.usersCharacters = function(email,cb){
  User.findOne( {'local.email' : email }).exec(function(err, user){
    if (err) console.log("shit");
    var _return = [];

    user.characters.forEach(function(err, i){
      Character.findOne({ "_id" :user.characters[i] }).exec(function(err2, dude){
        _return.push(dude);

        /* Can't think of a smarter way to return :( */
        if ( i == user.characters.length-1)
          cb(_return);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

routes.js

```
/* This doesn't work! I am wondering how I might be able to return this users characters -- 
 *
 * The error is here btw! TypeError: Cannot call method 'usersCharacters' of undefined -- line with character : ****
 */
app.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var UserSchema = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
    console.log(UserSchema);
    // ERROR ON THIS LINE! : (
    characters : req.user.usersCharacters(req.user.email, function(_characters){ 
                   console.log("list of characters: " + _characters);
                   return _characters;
                   res.render('profile.ejs', {
                     user : req.user, // get the user out of session and pass to template
                     characters : characters
                   });
```

here is a gist with more of my model file code:

https://gist.github.com/hassanshaikley/d4766251ec53feec8e84

Answer (score 1):

Methods that you add to `UserSchema` *after* creating the `User` model from it, won't be available on `User` model instances.

So create the method before creating the `User` model:

```
UserSchema.methods.usersCharacters = function(email,cb){ ... };

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

On a related note, only the first call to `mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)` processes the schema to create the `'User'` model.  Subsequent calls ignore the `UserSchema` parameter and return the existing model.

Answer (score 0):

JohnnyHK is correct that the order of creating a Mongoose model object is:

1. Create the schema properties using `var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({...});`.
2. Add additional functions to the schema using `UserSchema.methods.usersCharacters = ...`, as you have done.
3. Use the schema to create the model, as in `var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);`
4. Export the model using `module.exports = User;`

However, that is not the immediate cause of your issue. You are calling `.usersCharacters()` on an object called `user`. While it may have key-value pairs identical to those of a Mongoose document object, it is not a Mongoose document object. 
 Instead, it is a generic Javascript object. You must first look up the corresponding Mongoose document object in your database, using the following:

```
User.findOne( {'local.email' : req.user.email } )).exec(function(err, userDoc){
  if (err) console.log("shit");
  var characters = req.user.usersCharacters(req.user.email, function(_characters){ 
      console.log("list of characters: " + _characters);
      return _characters;
  });
  res.render('profile.ejs', {
    user : req.user, // get the user out of session and pass to template
    characters : characters
  });
});
```

Note that the `req.user` object passed to `res.render()` will only contain the properties sent in the request, which may be different from those in the `userDoc` object.

Do be aware, however, that I am currently having trouble accessing instance methods of documents returned from using `.findOne()`. If you run into that problem, you can check out my thread here: [Instance methods not defined for Mongoose findOne() query result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092433/instance-methods-not-defined-for-mongoose-findone-query-result?noredirect=1#comment89174043_51092433)