# Instance methods not defined for Mongoose findOne() query result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My problem is that I can't call a model instance method on the document returned from a `findOne()` query, even though I *can* successfully call the instance method on the same document before I save it to the collection.

First, the usual `require()`s, followed by schema creation:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const pwHash = require('password-hash');
const dbAddress = 'mongodb://localhost/18-652_Ramp_Up_Project';
const projectDb = mongoose.createConnection(dbAddress);

const exampleUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

// Instance methods of the User class:
exampleUserSchema.methods.checkPw = function(pwToAuthenticate) {
  return pwHash.verify(pwToAuthenticate, this.password);
};

// Retrieve the document corresponding to the specified username.
exampleUserSchema.statics.findOneByUsername = function(username) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    projectDb.collection('exampleUsers').findOne(
      {username: username},
      (err, existingUser) => {
        if (err) throw(err);
        return resolve(existingUser ? existingUser : null);
      }
    );
  });
};

// Constructor (through mongo);
const ExampleUser = projectDb.model('ExampleUser', exampleUserSchema, 'exampleUsers');
```

Now the interesting part: I can create a new user and call the instance method on it successfully:

```
// Create a test user and try out the 
const hashedPw = pwHash.generate('fakePassword');
ExampleUser.create({username: 'fakeUsername', password: hashedPw}, (err, newUser) => {
  console.log(newUser.checkPw('fakePassword')); // --> true
  console.log(newUser.checkPw('password123')); // --> false
  newUser.save((err) => {
    console.log('New user ' + newUser.username + ' saved.'); // --> New user fakeUsername saved.
  });
});
```

But when I try to call it on the document returned from a findOne() query, it's "not a function":

```
/* POST user login info. */
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

  // Try to look up the user in the database.
  ExampleUser.findOneByUsername(req.body.username) // Static method works.
      .then((existingUser) => {
        console.log(existingUser);
        if (existingUser && existingUser.checkPw(req.body.password)) { // Instance method doesn't.
          console.log('Access granted.');
        } else {
          console.log('Access denied.');
        }
      });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This produces:

```
POST /example/login 200 22.587 ms - 14
{ _id: 5b3d592d8cd2ab9e27915380,
  username: 'fakeUsername',
  password: 'sha1$ea496f95$1$6a01df977cf204357444e263861041c622d816b6',
  __v: 0 }
(node:40491) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: existingUser.checkPw is not a function
    at ExampleUser.findOneByUsername.then (/Users/cameronhudson/Documents/GitHub/18-652_Ramp_Up_Project/routes/exampleUsers.js:52:42)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668534/mongoose-nodejs-has-no-method-for-some-reason

Comment: @JohnnyHK While that thread bears similarities to this one, its problem was caused by calling an instance method on a non-document object from an http request. In my case, I am unable to call an instance method on a document object returned from a findOne() query.

Comment: What's returned from a `findOne` query is definitely a model instance. Does your `userSchema.methods.checkPw = function...` line appear before or after you call `mongoose.model` to create the `User` model.

Comment: Yes. I'll include a bit of my schema to make that clear.

Comment: This a fair bit of code, and it isn't complete. Could provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Ok, I will update my question.